# AjaxFileManager unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using TinyceEditor in my website and I'm using AjaxFileManager to upload images.

It works very good in my localhost, but in the remote server while uploading image an error appears

> Syntaxerror: unexpected token <

and uploading stops.

Please I need the answer quickly!

Comment: `Syntaxerror: unexpected token <` normally crops up when an html error page is returned instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

change ajax_file_upload.php in line 49:
from

```
$manager = new manager($upload->getFilePath(), false);
```

to

```
$manager = new manager(dirname($upload->getFilePath()), false);
```